# Display Parameters inside echo of a shell scrip

Tags: bash, shell

I am trying to generate a file while running the following anonymous block in a shell script function. I am reproducing only part of that fucntion. 
The code is.

```
echo " sqlplus -s $user_name/$password << EOF"
echo "set serveroutput on"
echo "set echo on"
echo "WHENEVER SQLERROR EXIT SQL.SQLCODE"
echo "declare"
echo "        l_workspace_id number;"
echo "        l_workspace_name varchar2(100) := '$workspace_name';"
echo "        l_application_id number := $application_id;"
echo "        l_parsing_schema varchar2(100) := '$user_name';"
echo "begin"
echo "    select workspace_id into l_workspace_id"
echo "      from apex_workspaces"
echo "where upper(workspace) = upper(l_workspace_name);"
echo ""
echo "    apex_application_install.set_workspace_id( l_workspace_id );"
echo "    apex_application_install.set_application_id(l_application_id);"
echo "    apex_application_install.generate_offset;"
echo "    apex_application_install.set_schema( l_parsing_schema );"
echo "    apex_application_install.set_application_alias( 'F' ||    apex_application_install.get_application_id );"
echo "end;"
echo "/"
echo "@f$APPLICATIONID.sql"
echo "commit;"
echo "exit;"
echo "EOF"
```

This echo then gets printed in another shell script file. The issue is when I am checking the .sh file generated I am getting the following output

```
sqlplus -s / << EOF
set serveroutput on
set echo on
WHENEVER SQLERROR EXIT SQL.SQLCODE
declare
    l_workspace_id number;
    l_workspace_name varchar2(100) := ;
    l_application_id number := ;
    l_parsing_schema varchar2(100) := ;
```

All the places where I kept $ is coming as blank. Can some one tell me where I am going wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

When you `echo` those lines, the variables get expanded to their values.
But that's not you want to do.
You want the variables to be expanded later,
when running the generated script.
To do that, you need to either:

- Escape all the `$` with `\$`
- Change all the `echo "..."` to `echo '...'`, replacing double-quotes with single-quotes, so that `$` will not be expanded

A third, much better option is to use a here-document with a label enclosed in `"..."` like this:

```
cat << "OUTER"
sqlplus -s $user_name/$password << EOF
set serveroutput on
set echo on
WHENEVER SQLERROR EXIT SQL.SQLCODE
declare
        l_workspace_id number;
        l_workspace_name varchar2(100) := '$workspace_name';
        l_application_id number := $application_id;
        l_parsing_schema varchar2(100) := '$user_name';
begin
    select workspace_id into l_workspace_id
      from apex_workspaces
where upper(workspace) = upper(l_workspace_name);

    apex_application_install.set_workspace_id( l_workspace_id );
    apex_application_install.set_application_id(l_application_id);
    apex_application_install.generate_offset;
    apex_application_install.set_schema( l_parsing_schema );
    apex_application_install.set_application_alias( 'F' ||    apex_application_install.get_application_id );
end;
/
@f$APPLICATIONID.sql
commit;
exit;
EOF
OUTER
```